# Coerce data.frame to list by row

Tags: r

Starting with a data.frame such as:

```
df = read.table(text = "ref1  code1,code2
           ref2 code3,code4,code5
           ref3 code6", stringsAsFactors=F)
names(df) = c('id', 'codes')
print(df)
    id             codes
1 ref1       code1,code2
2 ref2 code3,code4,code5
3 ref3             code6
```

wishing for an outcome something like this:

```
lst = list()
for(i in 1:3) lst[[df[i,1]]] = strsplit(df[i,2], ',')[[1]]
print(lst)
$ref1
[1] "code1" "code2"

$ref2
[1] "code3" "code4" "code5"

$ref3
[1] "code6"
```

How might it be possible to get to this point without (slow) iteration?  `as.list(df)` only works by column:

```
$id
[1] "ref1" "ref2" "ref3"

$codes
[1] "code1,code2"       "code3,code4,code5" "code6"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
lapply(split(df$codes,df$id),function(x) strsplit(x,split = ",")[[1]])
$ref1
[1] "code1" "code2"

$ref2
[1] "code3" "code4" "code5"

$ref3
[1] "code6"
```

Ananda's solution mentioned below is IMHO far superior:

```
setNames(strsplit(df$codes, ","), df$id)
```

Comment: Ah `split` is what I was after! But I do like your little `lapply` flourish :)

Comment: I would personally prefer `setNames(strsplit(df$codes, ","), df$id)`, but +1 for the concept in the `split` step.

Comment: @AnandaMahto Yeesh. I think you're being awfully generous with your praise of my unnecessary use of `split`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach.

```
> lst <- unlist(apply(df[,2, drop=FALSE], 1, strsplit, ","), recursive=FALSE)
> names(lst) <- df[,1]
$ref1
[1] "code1" "code2"

$ref2
[1] "code3" "code4" "code5"

$ref3
[1] "code6"
```

Also using `setNames` for naming the list as in @Henrik's answer

```
> setNames(unlist(apply(df[,2, drop=FALSE], 1, strsplit, ","), recursive=FALSE), df$id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this

```
library(splitstackshape)
ll <- concat.split.list(data = df,
                        split.col = "codes",                
                        drop = TRUE)[[2]]
names(ll) <- df$id
ll

# $ref1
# [1] "code1" "code2"
# 
# $ref2
# [1] "code3" "code4" "code5"
# 
# $ref3
# [1] "code6
```

**Update following @Ananda Mahto's comment. Thanks!**

```
setNames(concat.split.list(df, "codes")[["codes_list"]], df$id)
```

Comment: Or: `setNames(concat.split.list(df, "codes")[["codes_list"]], df$id)` (since we know what the resulting column would be, and for the `list` approach, `sep = ","` is the default setting). +1, by the way :)

Comment: @AnandaMahto, thanks for your comment and change of `split.col`. I missed the `names` part after I had read the data...